# error C2679: binary '<<' : no operator found which takes a right-hand operand of type 'std::string' (or there is no acceptable conversion)

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2012, c++11

Here's my code, how do I fix this error?

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    string title = "THE WORLD OF PIRATES";
    cout << title << endl;
    cout << " Welcome to the world of pirates";

    cin.get();

    return 0;
}
```

The error is

```
binary '<<' : no operator found which takes a right-hand operand of type 'std::string' (or there is no acceptable conversion)
```

Comment: Before submitting a question, please use google to see if a question and answer already exist. For almost all standard error codes, there is already an answer. You can use google to search this site only by adding site:stackoverflow.com in the search bar.

Comment: marking as duplicate without referencing the original is also just as pointless. This is the first result now in a google search.

Answer (score 66, accepted):

You forgot to `#include <string>`

using `std::string` without including it's header works on some compilers that indirectly import parts of `<string>` into their `<iostream>` or other headers but that's not standard and shouldn't be relied upon. Also they often break when you try to output a string since they only included a part of the implementation and are missing the part that implements the `operator<<`.

Comment: I had included <string.h>, which worked in vs2010 but not in vs2015. Thanks!