# Unable to print stack items using OOP C++

Tags: c++, oop, stack, iostream, cout

Hi can anyone help? I need to print the top element of a stack of Objects (in this case points) and i am unable to find a solution online. I have attempted changing the datatype of top or straight up calling pointStack.top() in the cout but i have had no luck. Note. I have not included the Pop function as error C2679 is the issue

```
#include <iostream>
#include <stack>

#include "point.h"

using namespace std;

int main(){
    stack<Point> pointStack;

    Point p;
    int i;
    int counter = 0;

    for (i = 0; i < 10; i++){
        p.pCreate();
        Point p1(p.getXPos(), p.getYPos());
        pointStack.push(p1);
        counter++;
    }

    while (!pointStack.empty()){
        Point top = pointStack.top();
        cout << top; // error C2679
        cout << pointStack.top(); // also error C2679
    }

    system("PAUSE");
    return 0;
}

#ifndef __Point__
#define __Point__

using namespace std;

class Point{
private:
int x, y;
public:
Point();
Point(int x, int y);
int getYPos(){ return y; }
int getXPos(){ return x; }
void pCreate();
};
#endif

Point::Point(){
x = 0, y = 0;
}

Point::Point(int a, int b){
x = a;
y = b;
}
void Point::pCreate(){
x = -50 + rand() % 100;
y = -50 + rand() % 100;
}
```

Comment: It would be nice if you provide [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).   You didn't show "point.h".

Comment: [error C2679: binary '<<' : no operator found](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22724064/error-c2679-binary-no-operator-found-which-takes-a-right-hand-operand-of) may help

Comment: Ok it's pretty basic but will do

Comment: It's pretty unlikely it will bite you, but you never want to use double underscores in a C++ identifier outside of a Standard library implementation.  [There's actually rules against it](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/228783/what-are-the-rules-about-using-an-underscore-in-a-c-identifier), so `__Point__` is illegal.

Comment: There's no OOP in here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to your description, I think you forget to overload the << operator, you should add a operator overload function for you `Point` class, check [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/476272/how-to-properly-overload-the-operator-for-an-ostream).

For example:

```
class Point{
...
public:
    friend std::ostream& operator<< (std::ostream& stream, const Point& p) 
        {cout<<p.getx<<p.gety<<endl;}
...
};
```

Plus, you forget to `pop` the element from the stack in your `while` statement, this will lead to infinite loop.

Comment: thank you, i viewed the MS example on the web now that i know what i was looking for, added 
"friend ostream& operator<< (ostream& stream, const Point& p);"

"ostream& operator<<(ostream& os, const Point& p)
{
 os << p.x << "," << p.y;
 return os;
}"

To code with great success

Comment: @RowanBerry My pleasure :)

Answer (score 0):

```
cout<<top;
```

doesn't work because point is a class created by you, the compiler cant print it.
You should print the individual element of point by yourself.
Like

```
     cout<<point.getx<<point.gety<<endl;
```

Or create an overload function for operator << in your class which does similar thing mentioned above.