# Insertion operator is not working with vector and I don't know why

Tags: c++, compiler-errors, linker-errors

So I was starting to write my code and I was going to test to see if I still remember how to cast, until I get a red line under my operator.
This is the compiler error:

```
Error C2679: binary '<<': no operator found which takes a right-hand operand of type 'std::basic_string<char,std::char_traits<char>,std::allocator<char>>' (or there is no acceptable conversion) (12)
```

I honestly never had a problem with outputting a string/vector so I do not know how to fix this. Can someone please tell me how to fix this. It would also be awesome if you could tell me what is wrong with the code.

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    vector<string>hello;
    hello.push_back("9");
    for (auto i : hello)
        cout << i << " "; <-- The first operator is underlined. Why?
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: This is C++, do not include C tag!

Comment: Try including `<string>`

Comment: @Jakub Gaweł  Include header <string>

Comment: Possible duplicate of [error C2679: binary '<<' : no operator found which takes a right-hand operand of type 'std::string' (or there is no acceptable conversion)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22724064/error-c2679-binary-no-operator-found-which-takes-a-right-hand-operand-of)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need one more include in your program:

```
#include <string>
```

While `<iostream>` does declare/define some string related functions, not all of them.

With some compilers, the iostream header incldues string internally, but that isn't required by the standard - and Visual Studio doesn't, that's why you receive this error.

Comment: @Dutow purely out of interest, I just checked and Apple LLVM version 8.0.0 (clang-800.0.42.1) compiles and runs the code fine without including <string>. So yes, it's VS specific in this case.

Comment: @ASMackay - So is the problem that you can use `std::string` without including the proper header, or that the compiler tells you that the code is in error?

Comment: @BoPersson To clarify; LLVM allows the use of std::string attempted in the question without including the proper header, but MSVC produces an error. I haven't formed an opinion on whether or not either behaviour should be considered a problem.