# Error printing std::string using std::string ptr

Tags: c++, string, stdstring

I am trying to print a std::string using std::string ptr as below but getting error:

```
Error   1   error C2679: binary '<<' : no operator found which takes
 a right-hand operand of type 'std::basic_string<_Elem,_Traits,_Ax>'
 (or there is no acceptable conversion)
```

Code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <iostream>

int main()
{
    std::string * strPtr = new std::string("Hello World!\n");
    std::cout << (std::string)*strPtr;

    delete strPtr;

    return 0;
}
```

What wrong I could be doing here ?

Comment: Which compiler are you using? Because in GCC 7.2 works. Also, the casting `(std::string)*strPtr` is not necessary.

Comment: [I can't replicate your error](https://ideone.com/HXNRqU). The code in the question is not the code that cause the error.

Comment: I was using Visual studio 2008

Comment: This is a complete duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22724064/error-c2679-binary-no-operator-found-which-takes-a-right-hand-operand-of but sadly I already used my flag on something else, if anyone wants to take over.

Answer (score 0):

Got it... I didn't include `#include<string>`. My mistake. After adding the header file it worked.

Comment: What does _"include #include"_ mean? Anyway, voting to close as caused by a simple typographic error.

Comment: Edited the answer...its string header file

Comment: This question might help somebody committing silly mistake like me and wondering whats wrong.